# HTML time tag - correct date format

Tags: time, tags, html

I am wanting to use the correct format and standards to put the time tag in my html document.

Is this the correct way to do it?

```
<time datetime="2014-03-26T12:48:42.733Z">26/03/2014</time>
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the link: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.8

Answer (score 3):

The Format is `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD`

> The date or time being specified. Explanation of components:
>
> ```
> YYYY - year (e.g. 2011)
> MM - month (e.g. 01 for January)
> DD - day of the month (e.g. 08)
> T - a required separator if time is also specified
> hh - hour (e.g. 22 for 10.00pm)
> mm - minutes (e.g. 55)
> ss - seconds (e.g. 03)
> TZD - Time Zone Designator (Z denotes Zulu, also known as Greenwich Mean Time)
> ```

So Yes

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_time_datetime.asp)

Answer (score 3):

The [`time`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) element defined in HTML5 must specify a time or date or both, or other applicable designation in a specific machine-readable format, as described in the draft. This designation may appear as the element content, e.g.

```
<time>2014-03-26</time>
```

If it does not (typically, when the content specifies a date or time in human-readable form in some language), the machine-readable designation must appear as the value of the `datetime` attribute, e.g.

```
<time datetime="2014-03-26">26/03/2014</time>
```

The notation in the question is not adequate, as the value of the attribute must be “a representation of the element's contents in a machine-readable format”, and a date and time denotation, down to milliseconds, can hardly be said to represent a date.

Note: There is no evidence of browsers or search engines making any use of `time` markup, so such markup is only potentially useful.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.datetime):

> A valid date-time as defined in [RFC 3339], with these additional qualifications:
>
> - the literal letters T and Z in the date/time syntax must always be uppercase
> - the date-fullyear production is instead defined as four or more digits representing a number greater than 0
>
> Examples:
>
> 1990-12-31T23:59:60Z
>
> 1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [RFC 3339](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/references.html#refsRFC3339) and [input type=datetime](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime.html#input.datetime.attrs.value)

Answer (score 0):

The spec [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.datetime) lays down the format. There's no mention of fractional time, so no - this is not correct.

However, this will be correct:

```
<time datetime="2014-03-26T12:48:42Z">26/03/2014</time>
```