# Html element <time> date format without HH MM SS

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, time, element

I am using HTML `<time>` element to display the date.I have to display only date-part.From back-end I am getting date "13/07/2016 00:00:00" with HH MM SS.

I used below line to convert date-time to date.

```
<time class="meta" datetime="DD/MM/YYYY">13/07/2016 00:00:00</time>
```

But still output is same "13/07/2016 00:00:00".

I was referring :-
[HTML time tag - correct date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214732/html-time-tag-correct-date-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some confusion regarding  tag.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time):

> This element is intended to be used presenting dates and times in a machine readable format. This can be helpful for user agents to offer any event scheduling for user's calendar.

In your code, `<time class="meta" datetime="DD/MM/YYYY">13/07/2016 00:00:00</time>`, the output will not change by format you specify by **datetime** attribute, because it is meant for machine reading, but the text part of this tag that is **13/07/2016 00:00:00** will be visible on  page to humans.

If you want to change format of output of this. I think you should use some sort of javascript to format this value, or for a hackish way, you can just split it by space and use first index for just date.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `<time>` tag incorrectly. The `datetime` attribute should be a valid date with an optional time string and it has no effect on the content of the tag.

A valid usage example:

```
<p>The concert took place on <time datetime="2001-05-15T19:00">May 15</time>.</p>
```

What you want to achieve is not possible with HTML only. You either format the date on the backend, or use Javascript.